# Angular material Error when mat-checkbox is imported

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm having some troubles with Angular Material, I've tried a lot of solutions but none of them work. This is what I'm trying to do :

I'm using Angular Material with Reactive Forms to make a `register` form, everything was fine until I added a `mat-checkbox` component. This is the `error` I get :

> ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl.

And this is my code :

**HTML :**

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-checkbox formControlName="check">
      Check me!
   </mat-checkbox>
</mat-form-field>
```

**COMPONENT :**

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required ],
    email: ['', Validators.required],
    check: ['', Validators.required ]
});
```

**MODULE :**

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RegisterFormComponent } from './register-form.component';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
 ],
 declarations: [
    RegisterFormComponent
 ]
})

export class RegisterFormModule { }
```

I imported the modules so that Angular Material works fine, implemented the form control name and I still got the same `error`. I tried to include the `mat-checkbox` in my *html* without the mat-form-field container and it works perfectly with no errors, but I really need to use the form field because I want to add some mat-error components to display validation messages.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: Try adding a name attribute, name="check"  along with formControlName.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The error means that the form field cannot find a compatible material input inside of it.

Do not use `<mat-checkbox>` inside `<mat-form-field>`.

> The following Angular Material components are designed to work inside a `<mat-form-field>`:

> - `<input matNativeControl>` & `<textarea matNativeControl>` (version 7 & newer)

> - `<select matNativeControl>` (version 7 & newer)

> - `<input matInput>` & `<textarea matInput>` (version 5 & 6)

> - `<mat-select>`

> - `<mat-chip-list>`

Source: [Official docs](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)

Comment: That's a very weird decision from AngularMD team - now how do I vertically align two form fields where one has `mat-form-field` with `input` inside and the other one has a checkbox but cannot use `mat-form-field` with its vertical layout styles... Cannot see any logic why mat-checkbox is not considered a valid form-field.

Comment: Please check this documentation page https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/examples

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the [checkbox documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview), I see that the use of checkbox is `supported` in the forms, both `reactive` and `template driven`. I was able to create a checkbox inside the form as follows.

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="selectedCourse.favorite" name="favorite">
        Favorite
        <input matInput>
    </mat-checkbox>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: It looks like a hack; wondering how does UI look. This may break other things and it is not the way that AngularMD recommended. I'd avoid doing that.